# How to use Markdown Slots in files other than their definition in VuePress (v1.x)?

Tags: vuepress

I am working with **[Markdown Slots](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/markdown-slot.html#why-do-i-need-markdown-slot)** in a VuePress (v1.x) page
and I want to reuse sections of Markdown in other `.md` files. To
do this I created a *Vue* component named `Reference.vue` which
employs the VuePress *Content* component.

The Reference.vue component works when it is used in the same
file as the slot definition -- but does not work when implemented
elsewhere.

> **Questions**
>
> - Is it possible to use Markdown Slots in a file other
>   than their definition?
> - If so, how is this functionality achieved?

Below are all the pertinent pieces:

**Directory Structure** (Scaffolded with `npx create-vuepress-site`)

```
docs
└─ src
   ├─ .vueress
   |   ├─ components
   |   |  └─ Reference.vue
   |   |
   |   └─ config.js
   |
   ├─ consumer
   |  └─ README.md
   |
   └─ reference
      ├─ README.md
      ├─ ref-1.md
      └─ ref-2.md
```

**config.js**

```js
module.exports = {

  ...

  themeConfig: {

    ...

    nav: [
      {
        text: 'Reference',
        link: '/reference/'
      },
      {
        text: 'Consumer',
        link: '/consumer/',
      }
    ],
    sidebar: {
      '/reference/': [
        {
          title: 'Reference',
          collapsable: false,
          children: [
            '',
            'ref-1',
            'ref-2'
          ]
        }
      ],
      '/consumer/': [
        {
          title: 'Consumer',
          collapsable: false
        }
      ]
    }
  },

  ...
}
```

**Reference.vue**

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <Content v-bind:slot-key="slotKey" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        slotKey: String
    }
}
</script>
```

**/reference/README.md**

```md
# Reference

## This Reference component DOES NOT render the slot defined in ref-1.md
<Reference slotKey="ref-1" />
```

**/reference/ref-1.md**

```md
## This Reference component renders the slot
<Reference slotKey="ref-1" />

::: slot ref-1
# Reference 1
:::
```

**/consumer/README.md**

```md
# Consumer

## This Reference component DOES NOT render the slot defined in ref-1.md
<Reference slotKey="ref-1" />
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want `<Reference slotKey="ref-1">` to lookup the named slot defined in `ref-1.md`. The confusing part is `ref-1.md` itself contains `<Reference slotKey="ref-1">`...is that file supposed to be recursive? If so, what would be the exit condition? Also, it seems to me that regular components with props would be the right tool for this problem (not slots). Can you share a link to a reproduction that shows your use case for this problem?

Comment: @tony19, to clear up the confusion about **recursion**, slots are not rendered in the markdown files -- `::: slot key ... :::` is not rendered until it is consumed, see this link to [Markdown Slots](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/markdown-slot.html#why-do-i-need-markdown-slot). My use case is also described in the link. Ultimately there are snippets of markdown I would like to *reuse* instead of rewriting upwards of 5 or more times. Does this help?

Comment: No, the use case still isn't clear to me, and it's not really described by the link because you're trying to refer to named slots from an external file. I don't understand why components can't be used instead here.

Comment: @tony19, I would like to use components but, **a** I don't know how to write Markdown in a Vue component and **b** I think using components to house the documentation would negate the VuePress [search](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/theme/default-theme-config.html#search-box) feature, which is why I am using [VuePress](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/getting-started.html) in the first place -- that being said, have you had success using components for documentation in VuePress?